# If $\ln x$ is integrable, then is $x \ln x$ also integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, logarithms

I have a very simple problem. Assume we have a finite measure $\mu$ on $[1,\infty)$, and
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty t ~d\mu(t) < \infty.
\end{align}
My question is if this implies
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty t \ln t ~d\mu(t) < \infty.
\end{align}
It would be nice if this is true but maybe someone sees a simple counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** $d\mu(t) = {dt\over t^2\log^{3/2}(t+1)}$.

Comment: ... so neither integral converges?

Comment: Yes, but with shifting it works, thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathrm{d}\mu = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^\alpha \ln^\beta t}$.  You should be able to show the two integrals converge if $\alpha > 2$ and, in the first case, $\beta < 1$, and in the second, $\beta < 2$.  Surely you can find something in $(1,2]$.

Comment: Yes, this even fits exactly at the form statet above, thanks. ;)